# Circular Buffer for Strings

Tags: data-structures, rust, circular-buffer

I'm buffering the last X lines of stdout, stderr & stdin of a process.
I'd like to keep the last X lines and be able to access a line by its id (line number).
So if we store 100 lines and insert 200 of them, you can access lines 100-200.
(In reality we want to store ~2000 lines.)

The performance case is insertion. So insertion itself should be fast. Retrieving will occasionally happen but is probably at 10% of the use case.
(We won't look into the output for most of the time.)

***Old approach, fragmenting***
I used a wrapping `ArrayDeque` and then kept book over the line-count, but this means we're using a `[Vec<u8>;100]` in the example above. An array of String thus an Array of `Vec<u8>`.

***New approach, with open questions***
My* new idea is to store data in one array of u8 and then keep book over start position and length of each entry in the array. The problem here is that we would need the book-keeping to be also some kind of ringbuffer and erase old entries the moment our array of data has to wrap. Maybe there are also better ways to implement this ? At least this takes full advantage of a ringbuffer and prevents memory fragmentation.

*thanks also to sebk from the rust community

Current easy approach

```rust
const MAX: usize = 5;

pub struct LineRingBuffer {
    counter: Option<usize>,
    data: ArrayDeque<[String; MAX], Wrapping>,
    min_line: usize,
}

impl LineRingBuffer {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            counter: None,
            data: ArrayDeque::new(),
            min_line: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn get<'a>(&'a self,pos: usize) -> Option<&String> {
        if let Some(max) = self.counter {
            if pos >= self.min_line && pos <= max {
                return self.data.get(pos - self.min_line);
            }
        }
        None
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, line: String) {
        self.data.push_back(line);
        if let Some(ref mut v) = self.counter {
            *v += 1;
            if *v - self.min_line >= MAX {
                self.min_line += 1;
            }
        } else {
            self.counter = Some(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Draft of the new idea questioned about:

```rust
pub struct SliceRingbuffer {
    counter: Option<usize>,
    min_line: usize,
    data: Box<[u8;250_000]>,
    index: ArrayDeque<Entry,Wrapping>,
}

struct Entry {
    start: usize,
    length: usize,
}
```

For whatever reason the current approach is still pretty fast, even though I expect a lot of allocations of different size (depending on the lines) and thus fragmentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go back to basics.

A circular buffer typically guarantees no fragmentation because it is not typed by the content you store, but by size. You might define a 1MB circular buffer, for example. For fixed-length types, this gives you a fixed number of elements you can store.

You're evidently not doing this. By storing `Vec<u8>` as an element, even though the overarching array is fixed-length, the content is not. Each element stored is, in the array, a fat pointer pointing to the `Vec` (starting point and length).

Naturally, when you insert, you will therefore have to:

1. Create this `Vec` (this is the fragmentation you're thinking of, but not really seeing, as the rust allocator is pretty efficient at this kind of stuff)
2. Insert the vec where it should be, shifting everything sideways if you have to (the standard circular buffer techniques are at play here)

Your second option is an **actual** circular buffer. You gain in fixed size and zero allocs if you do it right, you lose out on the ability to store *entire* lines with 100% guarantee of having an entire line at the start of your buffer.

Before we head into the wide lands of DYI, a quick pointer to [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/vec_deque.rs.html#47) is in order. This is a much more optimized version of what you implemented, albeit with some (fully warranted) `unsafe` sections.

---

## Implementing our own circular buffer

We're going to make a bunch of assumptions and set some requirements for this:

- We want to be able to store large strings
- Our buffer stores bytes. The entire stack is therefore dealing with owned `u8`
- We will make use of a simple `Vec`; in practice you would not reimplement this entire structure at all, the array is purely there for demonstration

The result of these choices is the following element structure:

```
| Element size | Data     |
|--------------|----------|
|  4 bytes     |  N bytes |
```

We are therefore losing 4 bytes ahead of every message to be able to get a clear pointer/skip reference to the next element (of maximum size comparable to a `u32`).

A naive implementation example is as follows ([**playground link**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=56d675da9eec606c6e9f0b7c4272f992)):

```rust
use byteorder::{NativeEndian, ReadBytesExt, WriteBytesExt};

pub struct CircularBuffer {
    data: Vec<u8>,
    tail: usize,
    elements: usize,
}
impl CircularBuffer {
    pub fn new(max: usize) -> Self {
        CircularBuffer {
            data: Vec::with_capacity(max),
            elements: 0,
            tail: 0,
        }
    }

    /// Amount of elements in buffer
    pub fn elements(&self) -> usize {
        self.elements
    }

    /// Amount of used bytes in buffer, including metadata
    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.tail
    }

    /// Length of first element in ringbuffer
    pub fn next_element_len(&self) -> Option<usize> {
        self.data
            .get(0..4)
            .and_then(|mut v| v.read_u32::<NativeEndian>().ok().map(|r| r as usize))
    }

    /// Remove first element in ringbuffer (wrap)
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
        self.next_element_len().map(|chunk_size| {
            self.tail -= chunk_size + 4;
            self.elements -= 1;
            self.data
                .splice(..(chunk_size + 4), vec![])
                .skip(4)
                .collect()
        })
    }

    pub fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        if self.elements <= idx {
            return None;
        }
        let mut current_head = 0;
        let mut current_element = 0;
        while current_head < self.len() - 4 {
            // Get the length of the next block
            let element_size = self
                .data
                .get(0..4)
                .and_then(|mut v| v.read_u32::<NativeEndian>().ok().map(|r| r as usize))
                .unwrap();
            if current_element == idx {
                return self
                    .data
                    .get((current_head + 4)..(current_head + element_size + 4));
            }
            current_element += 1;
            current_head += 4 + element_size;
        }
        return None;
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, mut element: Vec<u8>) {
        let e_len = element.len();

        let capacity = self.data.capacity();
        while self.len() + e_len + 4 > capacity {
            self.pop();
        }
        self.data.write_u32::<NativeEndian>(e_len as u32).unwrap();
        self.data.append(&mut element);
        self.tail += 4 + e_len;
        self.elements += 1;
        println!("{:?}", self.data);
    }
}
```

Do note again that this is a **naive** implementation aimed at showing you how you'd go around the problem of clipping strings in your buffer. The "real", optimal implementation would `unsafe` to shift and remove elements.

Comment: My base idea is the same as yours: Store the data as one big Array/Vec of u8 where you insert into the different Strings, avoiding any fragmentation. What I can't see from your approach is a) how you deal with accessing the n-th element. Or b) iterating over all elements in the ringbuffer. Or did I understand you wrong ? The VecDeque is used in my first code but it won't be able to give me specific lines / elements. Just specific bytes.

Comment: I edited my question in the hopes of making more clear that my question is exactly about porting the first approach over to the continuous array structure.

Comment: Added `get(usize)` to my implementation; to get an iterator, you obviously will need to build an interator. I'd strongly recommend **not** calling `get()` iteratively, but rather to keep a cursor to your state.

Comment: Oh thanks. I think I got your storage method now. This looks promising. This approach is indeed pretty good for insertion. What I don't get is how you would do this with rusts own vecdeque. Also it seems like you're dropping the last inserted entry if the insertion doesn't fit anymore ? Because I want to drop the first insertion, a wrapping circular buffer.
Have to investigate this at home a little bit more later.

Comment: I fucked up in naming my methods; `pop` is actually a `shift`, apologies for that. as for how you would use `VecDeque`, that was a comment regarding the previous method. Using one when you are storing variable length items defeats the performance gains of it.

Comment: Ok so I cleaned it up a bit and commented the different parts locally. I'll do some performance comparisions later but this already looks pretty promising and is neat idea, to store it in the buffer itself. Oh and I switched to NativeEndian for obvious reasons.

Comment: There's a couple of additional changes you can make. In my example I stored the length of strings as 4 bytes (i.e. `u32`); if you know your strings do not need this, you can probably drop down to `u16` to conserve some space (actual processor and memory access patterns will remain the same irrespective of preamble size). The biggest place where you could gain space is by keeping a lookahead of the first N elements to reduce the amount of times the loop iterates on insertion

Comment: I have to limit incoming data to u32 or allow usize.. It's uncontrolled, untrusted input.
Also there is one other limitation: I have to store some additional flag, an enum for the "kind" of data. Stdout/Stderr/Stdin/Status. So I'll probably add +1 byte.

Comment: This implementation has one big downside: splice is doing a "half an memory copy" on average.

Comment: That is a drawback you cannot really avoid, since the memory is contiguous and part of the same buffer as the rest. you are not dodging the copy, but the compiler does optimize some of the overhead in most circumstances.

Comment: I can avoid copying the whole buffer around by just using a clock-wise pointer and using that to count start/stop. Currently rewriting to take advantage of that.

Comment: It's released: [LineBuffer](https://crates.io/crates/linebuffer)